# Question about normal force acting on a mass on an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

[image: Source: Wikimedia Commoms]

Suppose we are given the free-body diagram above, with a mass on an incline at an angle $\theta$. If my coordinate axes are taken to be the regular $x-y$ plane rotated an angle of $\theta$ (*i.e.* the x axis is parallel to the direction of $mg \sin \theta$ and the $y$ axis is parallel to $mg \cos \theta$), then if there is no vertical motion, $N = mg \cos \theta$.

Now suppose I take my coordinate axes to be the $x-y$ plane but **NOT** rotated by any angle (*i.e.* the $x$ axis is parallel to the base of the triangle and the $y$ axis is parallel to the adjacent side), then if I want to resolve my weight $mg$ in the direction of $N$, wouldn't I need to make it $\frac{mg}{\cos \theta}$? (since in this case I would have to find the force whose vertical component is $mg$) If this is the case, no vertical motion would imply that $N = \frac{mg}{\cos \theta}$.

Does this mean that $N$ depends on my choice of coordinate axes? I might be making a mistake, but I'd appreciate if someone could point out the mistake in my logic.

Comment: You do not want to find "the force whose vertical component is ".   That "force" does not exist, so it doesn't have any components.  The real force is gravity;  it has components.  Regardless of frame, it is the force of gravity whose components you need.  BTW, you provided a nice diagram, thank you, but don't get confused.  There are three forces on the block, but someone *might* get confused by the extra two arrows.   Better to represent component vectors by a dashed line, or color... somthing to set them off from the real forces.

Comment: The magnitude of the normal force is invariant, but you can calculate the components of the force in different coordinate system for example in your x y system
$\begin{aligned}\overrightarrow{N}=N\cdot \overrightarrow{e}_{N}\\
\overrightarrow{e}_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
-sin\left( \theta \right)  \\
cos\left( \theta \right) 
\end{pmatrix}\end{aligned}$

Comment: Your assumption that $||\vec{N}||=\frac{mg}{\cos{\theta}}$ is wrong, notice that the friction is also contributing to making the block static in the y-direction on the second coordinate system.

Comment: Related? [Conservation of momentum for moving inclined plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241854/conservation-of-momentum-for-moving-inclined-plane/241862#241862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal force $\vec{N}$ is a *vector*, as indicated by my use of notation. As such, the expression does depend on the coordinate frame. However, the actual force is *independent of the frame of reference*.

1. In your first case, where you consider your $x-y$  axis to be parallel with the incline, the vector $\vec{N}$ has only a component in the $y$ direction. This means that

$$\vec{N} = 0\cdot \hat{x} + mg \cos \theta \hat{y}, $$

where the hatted vectors are unit vectors in the respective directions. The magnitude of $\vec{N}$ is, as you pointed out, $|\vec{N}| = mg \cos \theta$.

2. Now we consider the second case, where the $x-y$ axis is parallel to the ground. In this case, the normal force has to be decomposed in both the $x$ and $y$ directions, but now both components are non-zero. In this new coordinate system we call the vector $\vec{N}'=R(-\theta)\vec{N}$ to indicate that its algebraic expression looks differently, even though physically they are the same thing. Here $R(-\theta)$ (the minus sign is because the second coordinate system is rotated clockwise with respect to the first one) is a rotation matrix, which yields the following expression for $\vec{N}'$

$$\vec{N}'= -|\vec{N}| \sin\theta \, \hat{x} + |\vec{N}| \cos\theta \,\hat{y}\\
=-mg \cos \theta \sin \theta \,\hat{x} + mg \cos^2\theta \,\hat{y}.$$
You can see now that computing the magnitude of $\vec{N}'$ in this reference frame would yield the same result
$$|\vec{N}'|= \sqrt{m^2 g^2 \cos^2 \theta (\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2\theta)}=\sqrt{m^2 g^2 \cos^2 \theta }=m g \cos \theta.$$

I hope that helps.

Note:
You don't need matrices to do this. You can calculate the $x$ and $y$ components by pure geometry. I included the matrix to showcase a different point of view, but it is not essential. The point is that vectors look differently in different coordinate systems, despite being fundamentally the same object.

Answer (score 3):

Changing coordinate axis is not a physical change. The net value of normal reaction remains same.

If coordinate axis are chosen to be parallel to the incline -
Now as the block is at rest i am assuming it is due to friction. Let's say that the friction  force is $f$

**X-direction :$ \ \ N=mg \text { cos }\theta$**

 
**Y- direction :$ \ \ mg \text { sin } \theta=f$**

Squaring and adding above two we get : 
$$N^2+f^2=mg^2$$
Rearranging

$$N=\sqrt{mg^2-f^2}$$

Now when coordinate axes are parallel to the base of wedge

**Y direction**:
$N \text { cos } \theta+f \text { sin }\theta=mg$

Squaring it :

$$(N \text { cos }\theta)^2+(f \text { sin }\theta)^2 + 2Nf\text { sin }\theta \text { cos }\theta=mg^2$$

**X direction** :$N \text { sin }\theta-f \text { cos }\theta=0$

Squaring it :
$$(N \text { sin }\theta)^2+(f \text { cos }\theta)^2 -2Nf\text { sin }\theta \text { cos }\theta=0$$

Adding the two squaring term we get :

$$N^2+f^2=mg^2$$

$$ \text {or} $$
$$N=\sqrt{mg^2-f^2}$$

Hence proved.