# Free Body Diagram for a Body on a Smooth Inclined Plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

Consider a body of mass $m$ on a smooth inclined plane with the normal force and weight labelled as shown:

[image]

Now, usually when the forces are broken into its components, we get an FBD like this:
[image]

From this we can obtain the equation:

$$ \Sigma F_\perp = 0\quad \implies\quad N = mg\cos(\theta) \tag1$$

However, I tried resolving the forces along the x and y axes and obtained a diagram like this:
[image]

But this time I got a different equation:
$$ N\cos(\theta) = mg \tag2$$

Clearly, equation (1) and (2) aren't the same. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about normal force acting on a mass on an inclined plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563452/question-about-normal-force-acting-on-a-mass-on-an-inclined-plane)

Comment: There is no acceleration along the direction perpendicular to the inclined plane. This is why you equate $N$ to $mg \cos \theta$. There is acceleration along the x and y direction. Therefore, equating $N \cos \theta$ to $mg$ is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If instead of decomposing into perpendicular and parallel force components, you use the 'regular' $x$ and $y$ axis as you did to get Eq. (2), then you will have a non-zero acceleration in both $x$ and $y$ directions. So, what you really should end up with for Eq. (2) would be $$ma_y=mg-N\cos\theta\tag2$$
because the forces are **not** balanced. Therein lies the reason why we decompose into parallel and perpendicular components -- because the block will only slide parallel to the incline, so we can nicely conclude that $\Sigma F_\perp=0$. However, in the usual $xy$ coordinate system, there will be an acceleration in both $x$ and $y$ directions. So you can't just assume one of them is zero.

Comment: Oh, yeah! I forgot about the acceleration...Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with you analysis so far but you now need to consider what you are going to do with the horizontal $N\sin \theta$ force noting that the acceleration is going to be parallel to the slope.